# How would you retrieve an entire column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID     Name    Price
--------------------------------------
1      item1     10
2      item2     40
3      item3     10
4      item4     20
5      item5     50
6      item6     20
```

Say you had this table above and wanted to retrieve the following:

```
ID    Name    Price
5     item5    50
```

But you wanted to retrieve the above by using the highest price. I am currently using the below code.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(price) AS Price,
    Name,
    ID
FROM 
    ExampleTable
GROUP BY 
    Name, ID;
```

Comment: But 20 is not the highest price.

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?  The answer to your question would depend on that.

Comment: My bad, highest price is 50. Just fixed it. The database I am using is SQL Server.

Comment: Please try to make sure your sample data and expected result are *consistent*. Because I don't think they currently are, if I'm understanding the rest of your question.

Comment: how item6 will come in output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server we can try:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Price DESC;
```

If there could be more than one record tied for the highest price, and you also wanted to report all ties, then we could use `WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Price DESC;
```

If you want to use `TOP` to select only certain columns, then just list those columns out, e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, Price
```

to select only the `ID` and `Price` columns.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for, For future reference what if there was extra data and I only wanted the specific rows?

Comment: @Blake Did you mean to ask "and I only wanted the specific _columns_?"  My answer already gives the specific rows, with _all_ columns.

Comment: Oh yes my bad, specific columns.

Answer (score 1):

use top as your DBMS is sql server

```
    select top 1 * from your_table
    order by Price desc
```

You could also use window function

```
with t1 as
(
select * , row_number() over(order by Price desc) as rn from your_table
) select ID  ,Name ,Price from t1 where rn=1
```